#  How do I set up user's "Favorite Tags" and "Ignored Tags" tag subscriptions?

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, forms

This website shows user-specific **"Favorite Tags"** and **"Ignored Tags"** listing tags the user subscribed to. Based on these subscription lists, content is being sorted in "views".

- How do I let the users pick favorite tags?
- How do I create a "favorite tags" block like it is done on this site?
- How do I up Views to prioritize content assigned to subscribed tags?
- Is it possible to use a Flags-like module to assign flags to taxonomy terms?

Comment: Is it possible to use a Flags-like module to assign flags to taxonomy terms ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using the [Flag module](http://drupal.org/project/flag) to allow your users to pick "favorite tags".  It is still in beta for D7 however.

Also, in the future you could look at the [Flag Terms module](http://drupal.org/project/flag_terms) to allow your users to flag taxonomy terms.  That module is still in dev.

You can use [Views](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create lists of "favorite tags", etc.

Comment: I will have a look into the Flag Terms module, thank you ! Does Flag module allow to assign flags to taxonomy terms ?

Comment: Not by itself, that's what the Flag Terms module is for