# How to create a suggested content view using Flag and Flag Terms modules?

Tags: 7, views, taxonomy-terms, flags

I am using Flag and Flag Terms modules to allow users tagging the content and taxonomy terms they like or dislike.

How do I create a view or a block that shows and sorts content based on tags assigned to, the way that prioritizes tags the current user subscribed for ?

Set up as in my previous question:  [How do I set up user's "Favorite Tags" and "Ignored Tags" tag subscriptions?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/12227/2916).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just tried it out. I need to add it to my site too and the 50 points bounty was enough incentive to move it up on my list ;-)

After installing flag and flag_terms you create a new flag and select "Taxonomy terms" as the "Flag Type". Configure the text options, select a vocabulary (or many),  permissions and select the "Display link on taxonomy term pages" checkbox.

Then view a few terms on the standard term page and flag them using the new link.

Then create your view for content from your selected "vocabulary". The trick is that you have to add the "Content: Taxonomy terms on node" relationship first. Only then can you add the "(term) Flags: termflag (by current user)" relationship and select your "term flag" you entered previously. If you "require this relationship" it will only show you nodes where the term has been flagged.

[image]